# How would I remove all duplicates in Python List?

Tags: python

For example:

```
newList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

I need the list to be:

```
newList = [3]
```

Another example:

```
tempList = [["cheese", "ham"], ["spinach", "dressing"], ["cheese", "ham"]]
```

The list would be:

```
tempList = [["spinach", "dressing"]]
```

It can't use anything that won't work on unhashable items - the real list will have list stored in it. I also will have over 100,000 objects so speed is the biggest factor. I don't need the list to be in any sort of order.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
newList.sort()

i = 0
while i < newList.__len__()-1:
    x = 1
    while newList[i].__eq__(newList[i + x]):
        x += 1
        if not (i + x <= newList.__len__()- 1):
            break
    if x != 1:
        for j in range(i, i + x):
            del newList[i]
        i-=1
    i+=1
```

This works but I'm wondering if there is amore efficient way.

Comment: Would there be any possibility of converting your lists to eg hashable tuples and converting back?

Comment: The complexity of your algorithm will necessarily depend on the nature of the elements of your list and also on how you compare those same elements. How do you want to compare them? Which kind of elements are you sure your list could have?

Comment: Yes I could convert them to hashable tuples and back. That's a route I haven't tried.

Comment: My list right now contains a list of strings. It's similar to my second example, just much much bigger. As for comparing them, I'm open to suggestions I just need speed and, of course, the correct results.

Comment: @JoshuaEllingson Ok, but do you want an algorithm which assumes that the _domain_ of the elements of your list _is_ just _lists of strings_ or do you want it to cover other cases?

Comment: It can assume it's just a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend generating a new list. A simple loop would work:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

new = []

for x in lst:
    if lst.count(x) == 1:
        new.append(x)

print(new)

#output:

[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert everything to it's `repr` repersentation, find the unique elements using a `Counter` and then use `ast.literal_eval` to transform everything back into objects.  This will work for stuff like `[1, [1, 23], [1, 23]]`, but not for everything.

```
from collections import Counter
from ast import literal_eval

def unique_elements(iterable):
    c = Counter(repr(e) for e in iterable)
    return [literal_eval(k) for k, v in c.items() if v == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

tempList = [["cheese", "ham"], ["spinach", "dressing"], ["cheese", "ham"]]

Below function will return dictionary having value = 1.

```
 from collections import Counter
    dict = {}
    for j in newList:
        for i in Counter(j):
            if i in dict:
                del dict[i]
            else:
                dict.update({i:1})
    print dict
```

Other List = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]

Simply remove first for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def counter(newList):
   counter_list = {tuple(i) if not any(isinstance(i, b) for b in [int, str, float]) else i:newList.count(i) for i in newList}
   return [a for a, b in counter_list.items() if b == 1]

newList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
print(counter(newList))
```

Output:

```
[3]
```

When `newList` contains lists:

```
tempList = [["cheese", "ham"], ["spinach", "dressing"], ["cheese", "ham"]]
print(counter(tempList))
```

Output:

```
[('spinach', 'dressing')]
```